# time period count of multiple settimeout calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

During several ajax requests, dependant functions are being called at certain period of  time. My Question is, there any way to find the total time period(200+300+500) without using  events in settimeout function.

```
//main ajax calls using following functions
setTimeout(function(){
    avg(10,15,30);
    alert('I am triggered at 2ms');//dependant function 1 (calculate avg)
},200);
setTimeout(function(){
    total(50,100,30);
    alert('I am triggered at 3ms');//df 2(calculate total)
},300);
setTimeout(function(){
    vat_cal(180,12.5);
    alert('I am triggered at 5ms');//df 3(calculate vat % for total)
},500);
```

Assuming that I don't know how many times the setTimeout is being used.
So that If time factor is known it makes easier to load the data with notification.

Multiple ajax requests are killing data loading time. If I know the total time (200+300+500 = 1000). I can notify the user to wait upto a second.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to describe. Could you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function avg(x1,x2,x3)
{
 alert(x1+x2+x3)

}

function total(x1,x2,x3)
{
 alert(x1+x2+x3)

}

function vat_cal(x1,x2,x3)
{
 alert(x1+x2+x3)

}


$.when(  avg(10,15,30),total(50,100,30), vat_cal(180,12.5) ).done(function( x,y,z ) {
   alert("finish")  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems a bit vague. But if you want to repeat `setTimeout()` function for a several time, it'll be better to use `setInterval()` function.
I dont really get the result that you want, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Code is Here][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/asomani/2y0t60g5/2/

Use When and Then callback method and in the last ajax request complete call the time Calculate Method.

window.time1 = new Date().getTime();

function aCallback()
{
   window.time2 = new Date().getTime(); 
   total_time = (window.time2 - window.time1)

}

$.when($.ajax({
    data: {test:"1"}
}), $.ajax({
    data: {test:"1"}
}),$.ajax({
    data: {test:"1"},
  success: aCallback
}) ).done(function( x,y,z ) {
    alert(total_time ); 

});
```